# "prefered_external" property

Tags: android, google-play

I have my android app developed, I generate the apk file and it works perfect, the app is installed in my sd, but, when I install it from the market its installed in the phone.

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage.myapp"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.0"
android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Do i need to change minSdkVersion? or add somethhing to my developer Console?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to directly install?

Comment: SD, it works if I do it without the market, but it doesn't if I do it with it

Comment: [See this](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/) I think `Api-Level 7` Doesn't support this. So you've to use `Api-level` as `8` for minSdkVersion..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InstallLocation` mechanism works with Android ver 2.2(FROYO) and above, So the targeted device must be having at-least 2.2(Froyo) and above to get installed on Sdcard directly.